# javascript how to change local input method

Tags: javascript

As title ,I try jquery trigger to simulate shift key but it can't work well.
code like

```js
var press_e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
press_e.which = $.ui.keycode.SHIFT;
$("#button").trigger(press_e);
```

[link]: ( [Is it possible to simulate key press events programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events) )

How to use javascript to change input method?

Comment: Do you want to programmatically press `SHIFT` key?

Comment: yes,let my program press SHIFT key to change input method